# How to read environment config files on AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My serverless application fails to run on AWS in attempts to read environment configuration files. I keep getting the error file doesn't not exits. After reading the documentation this makes senses as there's no concept of a filesystem on AWS lambda. I have come across proposals to zip the configuration file with the source code but how do I go about that. My backend application is written in golang and frontend react and a monorepo project. Also using AWS cdk to setup the infrastructure. Also what are best practices to read env config files.

Comment: Without a minimal code example it's hard to say what's causing the error.

Comment: Getting the environment configuration from file is not recommended with AWS Lambda, as it don't have direct access to the file system. Instead you can use [AWS Lambda environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html). In golang you can load these env's with [os.GetEnv](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Getenv) or [viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper)

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC but I don't want to load the environment variables via AWS console but rather via code. In this case probably via CDK as I started using CDK. Is this a better approach also it seems any changes would force a redeploy right?